# Fitting test data to ground truth data

Tags: data-transformation, optimization, fitting

I have 2 sets of 3D imaging data from the same sample of biological tissue. Set A was gathered using an established method, and set B was gathered using a new, unvalidated method. My goal is to locate cells and record the x/y/z coordinate for the center point of each cell.

In set A, I have manually located and recorded the x/y/z locations of all visible cells -- this is my "ground truth" set. Similarly, I have x/y/z coordinates for cell centerpoints from set B, and I would like to test how well they fit with set A.

If the sets were paired, this fit could be measured as the sum of geometric distances, but inevitably there are cells in each set that are not detected in the other, so any solution would have to tolerate type 1 and type 2 errors.

I've found plenty of discussion of fitting data like this to models, but haven't been able to find as much discussion of fitting to ground truth data, and I expect this type of problem must be fairly common in machine learning. Any help would be much appreciated!